# Get color at a stop for a gradient

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to find color at a particular stop after creating a gradient.

```dart
Gradient g = SweepGradient(
  center: FractionalOffset.center,
  startAngle: 0.0,
  endAngle: math.pi * 2,
  colors: const <Color>[
    Color(0xFF4285F4), // blue
    Color(0xFF34A853), // green
    Color(0xFFFBBC05), // yellow
    Color(0xFFEA4335), // red
    Color(0xFF4285F4), // blue again to seamlessly transition to the start
  ],
  stops: const <double>[0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0],
)
```

Can I do something like `g.colorAt(0.95)` and get the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [`Color.lerp(a, b, t)`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/lerp.html) to linearly interpolate between two colors `a` and `b` at value `t`.

Using this we can make an extension on Gradient and create the method `colorAt(double)`:

```
extension GradientColorAt on Gradient {
  Color colorAt(double stop) {
    assert(0 <= stop && stop <= 1);

    final nextStopIndex = stops.indexWhere((element) => element >= stop);
    if (nextStopIndex == -1) {
      // happens when the last stop is not 1, where we return the last given color
      return colors.last;
    }
    if (nextStopIndex == 0) {
      // happens when the first stop is not 0, where we return the first given color
      return colors.first;
    }
    return Color.lerp(
      colors[nextStopIndex - 1],
      colors[nextStopIndex],
      (stop - stops[nextStopIndex - 1]) / (stops[nextStopIndex] - stops[nextStopIndex - 1]),
    );
  }
}
```

```
g.colorAt(0.95);
```

Now returns `Color(0xFF6377CD)` which is purplish.
Obviously this isn't going to be exact since gradient does not necessarily use lerp, but maybe you find it useful.